# Multiple if and else statements mess

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, refactoring

I am working on a windows forms app that uses a login window, and according to the selected username you get redirected to the form that belongs to that username. In a login window user selects his account name from a `ComboBox` and types a correct password in textbox. If wrong password is inserted, user gets a warning `MessageBox`. The problem is that my procedure with `if` and `else` statements for this login is a total mess.

My problem: If I correctly login with one of the accounts, new form opens, But all of the other `MessageBoxes` from other `else` statements with error `MessageBoxs` will still show up in new form. How can I design this differently. Note: `Guest` user does not need password.

My code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedUser = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox1.SelectedItem);

    if (selectedUser == "Guest")
    {
        Form3 form5 = new Form3();
        form5.Show();
        form5.Activate();
        this.Hide();
    }

    if ((selectedUser == "Admin") && (textBox1.Text== "password"))
    {
        Form1 form3 = new Form1();
        form3.Show();
        form3.Activate();
        this.Hide();
    }
    else MessageBox.Show("Password is incorrect!", "ERROR!");

    if ((selectedUser == "Limited") && (textBox1.Text== "limited"))
    {
        Form2 form4 = new Form2();
        form4.Show();
        form4.Activate();
        this.Hide();
    }
    else MessageBox.Show("Password is incorrect!", "ERROR!")
}
```

Comment: Try splitting your code into smaller methods!!

Comment: try to use nested if condition it will solve your problem

Comment: Hint: `else if` exists.

Comment: Nest your if statements and sort out your naming.

Comment: I'd attack this with the strategy pattern probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedUser = this.comboBox1.GetItemText      (this.comboBox1.SelectedItem);

    if (selectedUser == "Guest")
    {
        Form3 form5 = new Form3();
        form5.Show();
        form5.Activate();
        this.Hide();
    }
    else if ((selectedUser == "Admin") && (textBox1.Text         == "password"))
    {
        Form1 form3 = new Form1();
        form3.Show();
        form3.Activate();
        this.Hide();
    }
    else if ((selectedUser == "Limited") && (textBox1.Text     == "limited"))
    {
        Form2 form4 = new Form2();
        form4.Show();
        form4.Activate();
        this.Hide();
    }
    else{ 
        MessageBox.Show("Password is incorrect!", "ERROR!");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [`Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) usually:

```
Dictionary<string, Form> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Form>()
{
    {"Guest",  new Form3()},
    {"Admin", textBox1.Text == @"password" ? new Form1() : null},
    {"Limited", textBox1.Text == @"limited" ? new Form2() : null}
};

Form value;
dictionary.TryGetValue(selectedUser, out value);

if (value != null)
{
    value.Show();
    value.Activate();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to return immediately after each if branch:

```
if (selectedUser == "Guest")
{
    Form3 form5 = new Form3();
    form5.Show();
    form5.Activate();
    this.Hide();
    return;
}

if ((selectedUser == "Admin") && (textBox1.Text == "password"))
{
    Form1 form3 = new Form1();
    form3.Show();
    form3.Activate();
    this.Hide();
    return;
}

if ((selectedUser == "Limited") && (textBox1.Text == "limited"))
{
    Form2 form4 = new Form2();
    form4.Show();
    form4.Activate();
    this.Hide();
    return;
}
```

If the forms for the different users are quite similar. You can consider inheriting them from a common base class to reduce code duplication.

```
// "return" will cause this method to stop running immediately, so this 
// statement will only be run if none of the ifs gets run.
MessageBox.Show("Password is incorrect!", "ERROR!");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is you scattered your IF statement all over the place. You should combine them all into one.

```
string selectedUser = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox1.SelectedItem);

if (selectedUser == "Guest"){
    Form3 form5 = new Form3();
    form5.Show();
    form5.Activate();
    this.Hide();
} else if ((selectedUser == "Admin") && (textBox1.Text == "password")){
    Form1 form3 = new Form1();
    form3.Show();
    form3.Activate();
    this.Hide();
} else if ((selectedUser == "Limited") && (textBox1.Text == "limited")) {
    Form2 form4 = new Form2();
    form4.Show();
    form4.Activate();
    this.Hide();
} else {
    MessageBox.Show("Password is incorrect!", "ERROR!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend you write a method for things you do more than one time.

With that in mind, I think going for a switch statement might be a good option in your case:

```
switch(selectedUser)
{
    case "Guest": return ShowForm(new Form3());
    case "Admin":
        if(textBox1.Text == "password")
        {
            ShowForm(new Form1());
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Password is incorrect!", "ERROR!");
        }
        return;
    case "Limited":
        if(textBox1.Text == "limited")
        {
            ShowForm(new Form2());      
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Password is incorrect!", "ERROR!");
        }
        return;
    default: return;
}
```

And then for your ShowForm() Method:

```
private void ShowForm(Form FormToShow)
{
    FormToShow.Show();
    FormToShow.Activate();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't be afraid to extract logic into smaller and simpler functions. This can really help manage complexity.

For example, you could write a simple function to validate the credentials....

```
bool IsPasswordCorrect(string userName, string password)
{
    if (userName == "Guest") return true;
    if (userName == "Limited" && password == "limited") return true;
    if (userName == "Admin" && password == "admin") return true;
    return false;
}
```

And a simple function to choose the right form:

```
Form CreateFormForUser(string userName)
{
    if (userName == "Admin") return new Form1();
    if (userName == "Limited") return new Form2();
    return new Form3();
}
```

And now the rest is very simple:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedUser = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox1.SelectedItem);
    string selectedPassword = this.textbox1.Text;

    if (!IsPasswordCorrect(selectedUser, selectedPassword))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Password is incorrect!", "ERROR!");
    }
    else
    {
        var form = CreateFormForUser(selectedUser);
        form.Show();
        form.Activate();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

There are more clever ways to write this code, of course (e.g. using a factory, using a dictionary, etc.) but the more important concept, in my opinion, is breaking down a complex problem into simpler problems. Mastery of this mindset is essential when working on anything other than trivial software problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is a mess because you are trying to do too many things at once.

Separte concerns; create one method that validates user, create another method that shows the correct form to the user. I'll be using dictionaries (or maps) becuase in this type of scenario they are pretty convenient (I'll be newing them up as locals for clarity's sake).

User validation:

```
bool AuthorizeUser(string userName, string password)
{
    var users = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"GUEST", null},
        {"ADMIN", "admin"},
        {"LIMITED", "limited"}
    };

    var upperInvariantUserName = userName.ToUpperInvariant();

    if (users.TryGetValue(upperInvariantUserName,
        out var storedPassword))
    {
        if (storedPassword == null ||
            password == storedPassword)
            return true;
    }

    return false;        
}
```

And now showing the appropiate form:

```
void ShowForm(string userName, string password)
{
    var formSelectors = new Dictionary<string, Func<Form>>()
    {
        {"GUEST", () => new Form3()},
        {"ADMIN", () => new Form1()},
        {"LIMITED", () => new Form2()}
    };

    if (AuthorizeUser(userName, password))
    {
        if (formSelectors.TryGetValue(
            user, 
            out var formCreator))
        {
             var form = formCreator();
             form.Show();
             this.Hide();
             form.Activate();
        }
        else
        {
            //user not supported!
            throw new NotImplementedException(
                "This user is currently not supported.");
        }
    }
    else
       MessageBox.Show("Unknown or unauthorised user.");
}
```

Always remeber the golden rule: no task is small enough to not merit its own method. Break down everything to stupid little tasks; its hard to get them wrong.